# Dice Program in Java

Tags: java, loops, random, dice

I am making a dice simulator, and my task is to roll 4 dice at a time, add up each face of the die, and repeat that process as many times as I want. Then I have to record how many times each roll (the 4 dice added up) happened, and make a table.

What I am basically struggling with is how to loop my code so that it can repeat the roll as many times as I want, keeping track of the numerical value of each roll. Here is my code so far:

This is my program for the Die:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die
{
   private Random generator;
   private int sides;
   public Die (int s)
   {
      sides = s;
      generator = new Random();
   }

   public int cast()
   {
      return 1 + generator.nextInt(sides);
   }
}
```

And this is my Die Simulator program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DieSimulator
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Die d1 = new Die(6);
      Die d2 = new Die(6);
      Die d3 = new Die(6);
      Die d4 = new Die(6);
      final int TRIES = 1;
      for (int i = 1; i <= TRIES; TRIES +)
      {
         int n1 = d1.cast();
         //System.out.print(n1 + "");
         int n2 = d2.cast();
         //System.out.print(n2 + "");
         int n3 = d3.cast();
         //System.out.print(n3 + "");
         int n4 = d4.cast();
         System.out.print(n4 + n3 + n2 + n1);
         n = n4 + n3 + n2 + n1

      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

The commented section of the Die simulator program was just me trying to figure out how to post the numerical values of the roll.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the termination condition for your program? When should it stop? You also are not keeping track of each roll right now.

Comment: can you expalin what you mean by just me trying to figure out how to post the numerical values of the roll.?

Comment: Does this even compile? : `for (int i = 1; i <= TRIES; TRIES +)`

Comment: Just create a List, loop a couple of times, and add each result of the dice throw to the List

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= TRIES; i++)` ...

Comment: Hmmmm. Didn't I answer a question about Dice [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965149/dice-program-longest-streak-not-resetting). Maybe this will give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class which deals with the four dice:

```
public class Dice {
    private Die[] dice;
    public Dice(int noOfDice, int maxValueOfDice) {
        dice = new Die[noOfDice];
        for( int i = 0; i < dice.length; ++i){
            dice[i] = new Die(maxValueOfDice);
        }
    }
    public int cast(){
        int sum = 0;
        for( Die d : dice){
            sum += d.cast();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Keeping track of the values rolled is possible by using a map or an array:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Statistics {
    static int TRIES = 1000;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dice dice = new Dice(4, 6);
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        // roll TRIES times
        for (int i = 1; i <= TRIES; ++i){
            int value = dice.cast();
            if( map.containsKey(value)){
                map.put(value, map.get(value)+1);
            } else {
                map.put(value,1);
            }
        }
        // print all results:
        for( Integer key : map.keySet()){
            System.out.println("Value " + key + " rolled " + map.get(key) + " times");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the structure of your program, but i think it would be much simple if you didn't bother with another Class.

The easiest way to keep track of each individual roll is:

```
**int [][] results = new int[nDices][nRolls];**
```

You iterate through each throw easily by:

```
Random r = new Random();
int currSum=0;
int oneRollSum=0;
for(int i=0; i<nRolls;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<nDices; j++){
       results[j][i]= r.nextInt(6)+1;
       oneRollSum=oneRollSum+results[j][i];
       currSum=results[j][i]+currSum;
    }
    oneRollSum=0;

}
```